# How do I count the number of macro arguments passed to a variadic macro?

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

I'm already most of the way there:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#define COUNT(...) BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)
COUNT(1,2,3)
COUNT(1,2)
COUNT(1)
COUNT()
```

Running this with `-E` flag in GCC outputs the following

> 3 2 1 1

When what I need is:

> 3 2 1 0

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not set on using `boost preprocessor`, but I do need the solution to be variadic.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm running `g++` with the `-E` flag to expand the macro. It *is* verifiable.

Comment: `COUNT()` *is* passing one argument; it's just empty.

Comment: I've not used Boost.Preprocessor much, so this might be too complex, but does `BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_GREATER(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 1), BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), BOOST_PP_NOT(BOOST_PP_IS_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__)))` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `COUNT()`, you have one empty argument.

You may use something like:

```
#define PP_IS_EMPTY(...) (#__VA_ARGS__[0] == '\0' ? 1 : 0)
#define PP_COUNT(...) ((!PP_IS_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__)) * (BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Alternatively, variadic template may be a solution.

```
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t Count(Ts&&...) { return sizeof...(Ts); }
```

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was after :)