# Is there a less verbose way to initialize a tuple of heterogenous tuples (or similarly templated types)

Tags: c++, c++17, parameter-pack

I'm wanting to construct a tuple of hetergenous tuples but this seemingly requires an explicit constructor call for each member:

```
auto foo = std::tuple{
    std::tuple{1, "foo", 3},
    std::tuple{1, 2, 3},
    std::tuple{1.0, 2.0},
    // many more CTAD constructor calls
}
```

Basically I'm asking if a helper function, etc could make this look like the below example with homogenous inner types, where the inner constructor doesn't need to be called each time.

```
auto bar = std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string_view, int>>{
    {1, "foo", 3},
    {4, "bar", 6},
    {1, "baz", 3},
    // ...
};
```

So that I can hopefully have something like this:

```
auto baz = make_tuple_of_tuples(
    {1, "foo", 3},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1.0, 2.0},
    // ...
);
```

If this is impossible with `std::tuple`s, what about with a custom type where we control the constructors and deduction guides?

Comment: Have you tried writing such a function? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to construct *arbitrary* tuples where each element can again be *arbitrary* tuple?

Comment: If all subtuples have equal size and the possible types are chosen from a limited set known a priori, it is possible to have a formally simpler syntax. Not sure it's worth the trouble though.

Comment: Suppose you only can rely on pre-processor magic, pure C++ means would rely on being able to define a variadic list of variadic template parameters, something like `template <(typename ... Inner) ... Outer>`, or whatever it should look like – which is not supported. A variadic macro allowing `auto t = TUPLE_OF_TUPLES((a, b, c), (d, e, f), (g, h, i));` might be doable though pretty sure requiring quite a lot of work

Comment: (determining number of arguments, possibly including none at all for empty tuple, dispatching to specific sub-macros according to number of arguments, and analogously dispatching the inner tuples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ would require some way of dynamically specifying sets of variadic template arguments (something like `template <typename <typename ... T> ... U>` or whatever the syntax should look like), which is not supported, so out of luck so far.

You can achieve something similar with a bit of pre-processor magic, though:

```
#define TUPLE_OF_TUPLES(...) EVAL(CONCAT(TUPLE_OF_TUPLES_, COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__))

#define EVAL(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define COUNT(...) 2 // TODO: appropriate counting macro!
#define CONCAT(X, Y) CONCAT_(X, Y)
#define CONCAT_(X, Y) X ## Y 

#define TUPLE_OF_TUPLES_2(X, Y) EVAL(std::tuple(std::tuple X, std::tuple Y));
// TODO: analogously macros for 1, 3, 4, 5, ... arguments
```

Counting macro arguments is discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198787/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-macro-arguments-passed-to-a-variadic-macro) (though in given case you only can use the pre-processor solution!).

Demonstration on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7Kr6efb7x), though only tested for GCC, other compilers (especially MSVC) might or not need adjustments...

Be aware, though, that pre-processor magic is more error prone than standard C++, so use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

`{..}` has no types, and can only be deduced for `std::initializer_list` or C-arrays.

Your usage doesn't match, so you cannot use deduction.

Types should be provided:

```
auto foo =
    std::tuple<
        std::tuple<int, const char*, int>,
        std::tuple<int, int, int>,
        std::tuple<double, double> /*..*/>{
    {1, "foo", 3},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1.0, 2.0},
    // many more CTAD constructor calls
    };
```

or you have to use `std::tuple` "prefix" for each element (as you do):

```
auto foo = std::tuple{
    std::tuple{1, "foo", 3},
    std::tuple{1, 2, 3},
    std::tuple{1.0, 2.0},
    // many more CTAD constructor calls
};
```